# matplotlib.lines.Line2D message and absence of graph after plt.show() or %matplotlib inline executed before

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm learning pandas and I'm using Jupyter notebook in a virtual environment. when I create a graph in this way `graph1=sakila['film_replacement_cost'].plot(kind='density',figsize=(20,10))` and I try to add a vertical line with this command `graph1.axvline(sakila['film_replacement_cost'].mean(),color='red')` I obtain

`<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1f3df6e34c0>`. Where is my mistake? I read I have to execute `%matplotlib inline` and I've done it in my first three cells of code

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sqlite3

%matplotlib inline
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community my problem was the absence of the graph after all commands, now I solved the issue thanks to the way written below

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue: my mistake was the code for the vertical line executed in cell different from that one of the code for the first graph. So codes
`graph1=sakila['film_replacement_cost'].plot(kind='density',figsize=(20,10))` and `graph1.axvline(sakila['film_replacement_cost'].mean(),color='red')` must be in the same cell.